# Back-propagation algorithm converging too quickly to poor results

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, backpropagation, feed-forward

I'm trying to implement the back propagation algorithm for a multi layer feedforward neural network, but I'm having issues getting it to converge to good results. The reason being, the gradient descent gets stuck on a plate of the root mean squared error.

[image]

As you can see in the graph, there is very little change in the rms value for the first 70 epochs or so. Therefore the gradient descent things its found a minimum and stops. To fix this I set a requirement that the rms error must be below 0.3 in addition to the rate of change being below a given value. However, I don't think this is good as I believe there is something wrong with my implementation.

Below is the ruby code:

```
def train eta, criteria
    rms = 1
    old_rms = 0

    rms_window = Array.new 20, 0
    new_avg = 10
    old_avg = 0
    diff = 100 
    epoch = 0

    @data[:training].shuffle!

    while (diff > criteria || rms > 0.3) do
    #while (diff > criteria) do

        rms = 0
        old_avg = new_avg
        new_avg = 0

        classification_error = 0
        sample_num = 0

        @data[:training].each_with_index do |s, s_i|

            # Forward Propagation

            inputs = [1, s[1], s[2]]

            @hidden_layers.each_with_index do |hl, hl_i|
                outputs = Array.new

                # Bias Term
                outputs << 1

                # Compute the output for each neuron
                hl.each do |p|
                    outputs << p.compute_output(inputs)
                end

                inputs = outputs
            end

            # Compute System Outputs
            outputs = Array.new
            @outputs.each do |p|
                outputs << p.compute_output(inputs)
            end

            # Comput Errors
            errors = Array.new
            desired = @desired_values[s[0]-1]

            @outputs.length.times do |x|
                errors[x] = desired[x] - outputs[x]
                rms += errors[x]**2
            end

            decision = outputs.each_with_index.max[1]

            if decision+1 != s[0]
                classification_error += 1
            end


            # Back Propagation

            gradients = Array.new
            local_gradient = Array.new
            next_layer = Array.new

            @outputs.each_with_index do |o, i|
                local_gradient << errors[i] * o.activation_prime(o.output)

                o.weights.length.times do |x|
                    o.weights[x] += eta * local_gradient[i] * o.inputs[x]
                end
            end

            gradients << local_gradient

            next_layer = @outputs

            @hidden_layers.reverse_each do |hl|
                local_gradient = Array.new

                hl.each do |p|
                    gradient = 0

                    gradients.last.each_with_index do |g, i|
                        gradient += g * next_layer[i].weights[p.index+1]
                    end

                    gradient *= p.activation_prime(p.output)
                    local_gradient << gradient

                    p.weights.each_index do |x|
                        p.weights[x] += eta * gradient * p.inputs[x]
                    end
                end

                gradients << local_gradient

                next_layer = hl
            end

            if s_i == 0
            #puts "Epoch: #{epoch}\nOutputs: #{outputs}\nGradients:\n#{gradients[0]}\n#{gradients[1]}\n#{gradients[2]}\n\n"
            #puts "Epoch #{epoch}\nError: #{errors}\nSE: #{rms}"
        end

        end

        rms = Math::sqrt(rms / (@data[:training].length * 4))

        rms_window[0] = rms
        rms_window.rotate!

        rms_window.each do |x|
            new_avg += x
        end

        new_avg /= 20

        diff = (new_avg - old_avg).abs

        @rms << rms
        epoch += 1

        if classification_error == 0
            break
        end

        #puts "RMS: #{rms}\tDiff: \t#{diff}\tClassification: #{classification_error}\n\n"
    end

    self.rms_plot "Plot"
    self.grid_eval "Test", 250
end
```

The graph shown is for a 2-hidden layer network with 5 neurons in each hidden layer. There are 2 inputs and 4 outputs. Perhaps this is normal behavior, but something just seems off to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you initialising the weights and whats your learning rate?

Comment: The weights are random values between -0.1 and 0.1. The learning rate is 0.1

Answer (score 0):

There are many parameters that need to be tuned to get a multi-layer neural net to work. Based on my experiment, my first suggestions are:

1- give it a small set of synthesized data and run a baby project to see if the framework works.

2- Use a more convex cost function. There is no function that guarantees convexity, but there are many functions that are more convex that RMS.

3- Try scaling your input data in (-1,1) and output data in (0,1).

4- Try different values for learning rate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to whats already been said:

- vary the range of the initial weights a little more (0 - 1 for example)
- make sure your input data are properly normalised - i fell this can't be said often enough
- vary the learning rate, start with sth like 0.05 and keep increasing/decreasing in small steps (if you find that changing your learning rate has a too extreme effect on the network's performance, then you may haven't normalised your input data appropriately)
- shuffle the input data before every epoch
- try using momentum (this essentially means, increase the learning rate while the gradient is steep, decrease if it becomes flatter), this often helps to jump over local optima
- try using regularisation
- experiment with the structure (add another hidden layer, increase the number of units in the hidden layer)